# undefined() used as a function

Tags: javascript, undefined

I was reading a [article](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2012/03/20/debugging-maps-google-maps) on javascript debugging session, where author needed a way to get into removeChild of Element for knowing, which code is removing a particular element at run time.

So he used following code for purpose

```
javascript:void(Element.prototype.removeChild=function(){undefined()})
```

As far as I know, "undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope."*(Quoted from MDN)* typeof which being undefined.

In the next line, author says that he gets the stack trace(Note that he is working with opera and dragonfly).

I have tried executing this code, and it works if used at it is, but If I try to use only

```
undefined()
```

It does give me error "TypeError: undefined is not a function", which I understand.

Can anybody please explain how the mentioned code is working as valid javascript and how it solves problem of getting stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the author calls `undefined()`, it causes an error to occur, which he's catching in the debugger so he can figure out who's calling `removeChild` on that element.

Another approach would be to use the `debugger;` statement instead, which forces a breakpoint if the debugger is open.

Comment: yeah, that would have made more sense and could have made it easy to understand....

Answer (score 3):

This works specifically because `undefined` is not a function, which means that when the `removeChild` function is called, it throws that same error. This produces that oh-so-useful stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

It throws an exception on purpose.

> A fast way to find the code that would call removeChild() would be to
>   simply make removeChild() throw an exception

You could also do something like:

```
javascript:void(Element.prototype.removeChild=function(){debugger;})
```

To start the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but as far as I can tell what he did was make an *invalid* call so the debugger would open when trying to execute it, thereby allowing him to see where `removeChild` was being called from. So his `undefined()` is just as invalid as yours, that's its point.